# Splitting list in python

Tags: python

I have a list I'd like to split or divide into multiple sub lists. It would be nice for it to be in order but it doesn't have to. I'd like to split it into 3-5 lists if possible. At the moment I'm using the following code but I'd like to know if there's a better way to do it.

```
data_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']

print [data_list[i::3] for i in range(3)]

#output => [[1, 4, 7, 10], [2, 5, 8, 11], [3, 6, 9]]
```

The list will be of random length. Sometimes it can be 2 other times it can be 103 elements (w/ remainders). I know there have been other posts for this but I haven't found a good answer. Was hoping to change that this time around...any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: this code output this: `[['a', 'd', 'g'], ['b', 'e'], ['c', 'f']]`

Comment: Do you have no conditions for the sublists? Do you want them to be of equal size? Should elements that are "close" be in the same sublist? Why do you split the list into sublists?

Comment: @Jonathan what is the problem with this way?

Comment: @Lynch, thank you. I copied and pasted the wrong test output.

Comment: @syntonym, no real conditions. As long as i can split them up and cover all elements. I'm a little confused as to what the [i::3] means. Can you help me understand that?

Comment: @salparadise: one limitation I've noticed from this method is that if I provide a short list it creates empty sublists. For example: with a data_list of 3 elements and [data_list[i::5] for i in range(5)] .

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what means a better way for you but still, here's my shot:

```
import random

def split(data_list):
    new_list = []

    while len(data_list) != 0:
        add = random.randint(3,5)
        separed_list = []

        for i in xrange(add):
            if len(data_list):
                separed_list.append(data_list.pop(0))
        new_list.append(separed_list)

    print(new_list)

split(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'j']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way:

```
import math

def create_sublist(data_list, num_sublists):
    sublist_length = math.ceil(len(data_list)/num_sublists)
    list_of_sublists = []
    while data_list != []:
        sublist = []
        for i in range(min(len(data_list), sublist_length)):
            sublist.append(data_list.pop(0))
        list_of_sublists.append(sublist)
    print(list_of_sublists)

create_sublist(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j'], 3)
>>> [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['e', 'f', 'g', 'h'], ['i', 'j']]
```